# did I just program a pendulum, or something that just *looks* like a pendulum?

Tags: python, pendulum

i've spent some time trying to figure out how to simulate the motion of a pendulum, and i've got something that looks like its a pendulum, but i know that doesn't mean it *is* a pendulum! i realise the code isn't as clean as it could be but i'm fairly new to this so my main issue is making sure it works!

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math
import statistics
import numpy as np

A = 80
l = 100
g = 9.81


plt.ion()

for t in np.arange(1, 300, 0.4):
    w = math.sqrt(g/l)
    x = A*math.sin(w*t)
    v = w*A*math.cos(w*t)
    #h = -(1/2*(v**2))/9.81
    h1 = math.sqrt(l**2 - x**2)
    if v == 0:
        x = A
    h = l - h1
    px = 0
    py = 50
    x1 = np.arange(-20, 20, 0.5)
    m = (h-py) / (x-px)
    C = 50
    y = m*x1+C
    plt.clf()
    plt.errorbar(x, h, fmt = 'o', markersize = 20)
    #plt.plot(x1,y)
    plt.xlim(-100, 100)
    plt.ylim(-15, 100)
    plt.show()
    plt.pause(0.01)
```

Comment: Since this could be entirely expressed through mathematics, I think asking this on a math or Physics Stack Exchange site would be more likely get you the answer you want. We're just mainly programmers here, if there are physicists browsing then that would help you but it's not a guarantee. If you want a guarantee that people will know the physics, StackOverflow is not the best place to ask this.

Comment: it looks good, not sure if it's because of how i'm interpreting it, but i think your sqrt(g/l) should be sqrt(l/g) instead

Comment: i was wrong, you're working off the angular frequency, not the period. should be good